# How can I connect 2 headset microphones to my Macbook Pro so that we can both speak AND hear sound effects from the Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, microphone

This is for podcasting purposes. I just can't seem to figure it out. We both need to be able to speak and hear whatever noises/sound effects coming from the computer as all of it is being recorded. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have three sources - two mics and the computer which is also doing the recording.

What you need is a mixer like the [PreSonus 4x4](http://amzn.to/1qZhYVh) (I don't know of a 3 channel mixer).  This will give you control over the sound levels and profile of each source as well as a way to record them all on your computer.

[image]

I personally have used these in courtrooms (the 16 channel versions) to record from all microphones and audio sources.  They worked flawlessly.

The way it will work is like this:

- The two mics can go into the "instrument/mic" inputs
- The computer audio out can go to one of inputs
- The headphones connected to the headphone port (you can use a splitter here)

Comment: Got it. Sounds good. What if we were to use USB Mic/Headset all in one. Is there something out there that will work for us?

Comment: Typically, I haven't seen a system (PC or Mac) that could use two inputs at a time.  When you choose an input, it is limited to one selection.  2 USB microphones would be two different inputs so you would be switching.  At minimum you would need software to mix the two, but I am not familiar with any.  Remember, the USB mic/headset would show up as an input/output audio device.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to plug an "iPhone-style" headset into the audio jack and then use a headset with a USB connector for the other person. Just search for "USB headset with microphone." There are quite literally thousands to choose from.

The only question that remains is will you be able to use both microphones at the same time. That *may* require special software. I am not sure as I have never tried this specific setup.